# What rare cars are available, and how do I find them?

Tags: forza-horizon

I am trying to track down all the Barn Finds.

Where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of cars:

- Finley Dam: 1981 BMW M1
- Gladstone: 1954 Mercedes-Benz 300SL Gullwing Coupe
- Eagle Ridge: 1992 Bugatti EB110 SS
- Red Rock: 1964 Aston Martin DB5 Vantage
- Montano Plains: 1971 Plymouth Cuda 426 Hemi
- Bunker: 1956 Jaguar D-Type
- Carson: 1965 Shelby Cobra Daytona
- Redfoot Ranch: 1959 Aston Martin DBR1
- Beaumont: 1957 Ferrari 250 Testa Rossa

And here is a guide:

Have fun looking for them.